# Density for multiple columns at a time in r

Tags: r

I have an input file like this

```
V1 V2 V3 V4.............V60 
11 22 33 44.............89 
21 98 22 33.............09 
33 44 55 78.............20
```

The above file has more than 3000 rows with 60 columns in each row.

When I try using `density(data, kernel="gaussian", bw=15)` at my r prompt, it is generating an error saying

```
Error in density.default(data) : argument 'x' must be numeric
```

But, when I try `density(data$V1, kernel="gaussian", bw=15)`, it works fine.

I was wondering if there is a single command to calculate the density of entire file instead of doing it for every single column 60 times.

Comment: Do you want 60 densities or 1 single combined density

Comment: Hi @csgillespie, I do need all 60 densities for 3000 records. Is there a way to generate densities for each value? I mean can another output file containing densities resembling my input file be generated? Sorry for very basic question as I come from biology background.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you might be looking for `sapply` or `apply`.
you can use

```
 apply(myDataName,  2,  density, kernel="gaussian", bw=15)
```

if your columns are `factor`s instead of `numeric`, you will need to convert those first.

Comment: Thanks @Ricardo. But, does the value 2 mean anything above? Your code is generating 60 densities. It works. But, I was also wondering for each value in the input file, is there a way to get density?

Comment: yep, the `2` refers to columns or more specifically to the 2nd dimension (equivalent to the order of info you would get back from `dim(x)`). Fore more info on apply check out `?apply` and you can also search through here as there are plenty of questions on here covering the `*apply` functions

Comment: @jsmith, to the second part of your question:  how specifically are you defining "each value"?

Comment: @jsmith, reading over your comment to csgillespie, perhaps you do want 1 single density?

Comment: Hi @Ricardo, here is what I am expecting.

The following would be my density output file

V1 V2 V3 V4.............V60 
D11 D21 D31 D41.............D601 
D12 D22 D32 D42.............D602

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Most likely your `data` object is a data frame (this is the default when reading data using tools like `read.table` and `read.csv`).

If you want to process each column (create a seperate density plot for each column) then you can use the `lapply` function.

If you want one single density based on all the data (the columns don't mean anything), then you can use the `unlist` function to convert it all to one big vector.  Better may be to use the `scan` function instead of `read.table` to load the data into a vector to begin with and skip the data frame all together.

Comment: Thanks @Greg. But the above apply command by Ricardo is giving 60 densities. I was wondering about the possibility of calculating density at each value. So, my density file will carry the same data format as my input file.

Comment: @jsmith, do you want a density for each row?  in that case you can use `apply` like above, just use 1 instead of 2.